# Weird screen output

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, intel

[image: Ubuntu screen]

Does anyone know how to fix this weird screen output?

```
    ~$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GF119M [GeForce 610M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:32 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-e7ffffff memory:e8000000-e9ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Comment: Its an issue on NVIDIA side in their latest drivers.